# ElseIf vs Else If

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, syntax, semantics

For years now I've been using `Else If` to code in VBScript...

```
If a = b Then
    ...
Else If a = c Then
    ...
End If
```

Which seems to work as required. I've also seen many sites on the web that use `Else If`, excepting MSDN that uses `ElseIf`.

Is there a difference between `ElseIf` versus `Else If`?

### Snippet

<strike>Here's one I coded earlier that's working just fine through Classic ASP:</strike>

```
If IsDate(wD) Then
    wS = wD
Else If wD&"" <> FormatDisplayDate(wS) Then
    wS = WeekStart(Date())
    wD = FormatDisplayDate(wS)
End If
```

Here's a snippet from an older piece of code, written by someone else...

```
if opip = "IP" then
    opip = "In Patient"
Else If opip = "OP" then
    opip = "Out Patient"
End If
```

None of these are run through a compiler, however, it's all interpreted.

Ignore that junk - I messed up a search and replace in the IDE.

Comment: The code you published does not compile. So I wonder what you did for all those years.

Comment: Like @Ekkehard.Horner said that will not work you will get `Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected 'End'`, so are you sure that is the correct syntax used? The only way that would work is if you added an extra `End If` below the existing `End If` which basically changes the `Else` into a nested `If` which isn't the same thing.

Comment: I too am confused by this question; can you provide a code snippet which actually compiles and runs that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Until then, an amusing diversion: predict whether this single-line `If` statement should compile, given that there are `sub`s `Foo` and `Bar` and Boolean expression `X`: `If X Then Foo Else Bar`.  Any VBScript experts out there care to give it a shot?

Comment: @EricLippert: Yes that should work.  I've used similar expressions before.

Comment: @Paul: OK, try it! See if you are surprised.

Comment: @Paul it would appear not... `Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error`.

Comment: Missing the `:` before the `Else`.

Comment: No fair @EricLippert you actually developed the compiler! :p Is it todo with the shorthand `If` not understanding they are `Sub`s? This works `If x Then Call foo Else Call bar`.

Comment: @Lankymart: Correct! There is a bug in the single-line `If` parser that I never fixed. It attempts to parse `Foo Else` as a statement and fails, rather than detecting that the `Else` ends the statement after the single token `Foo`. There's no good reason why it was never fixed aside from the fact that it simply was not judged to be a high-priority issue.

Comment: I assure you that VBScript running in Classic ASP is compiled; it is compiled to a proprietary undocumented bytecode language which is then interpreted.

Comment: @EricLippert I tend to use `Call` when calling `Sub` procedures so I've never come across this bug, I feel as though I've learned something today. Thank you.

Comment: @EricLippert: This should also resolve, in that case, when a colon is introduced between  the If and Else statements, however that would make it a two liner, really.

Comment: @Paul isn't that just converting it to a normal `If` as a opposed to a shorthand `If`, so the bug will not show?

Comment: @Lankymart: Yep - that's basically what I was saying.

Comment: Oh! Man! You know what - I feel like such an idiot. I've been flicking around between several different languages recently, and I'm simply thinking of JavaScript. I swear I'm losing my marbles!  Sorry for the effort you've all put in, but thank-you all the same. @Ekkehard.Horner, LEric Lippert and Lankymart, you're all absolutely correct, of course.

Comment: It's a shame there isn't a `Close this thread because I'm an idiot` option in the list.

Comment: @EricLippert @lankymart In VB6 there is auto correct (afaik the only autocorrect) for `EndIf` being changed to `End If`.

Comment: @Lankymart WordBasic Ver 2 accepts `EndIf` or `End If` hence VB6 auto correct. The person is remembering `EndIf` not `ElseIf.` QBasic also auto corrects `EndIf` to `End If` but not `Else If`.

Comment: @Noodles what are you on about? Sorry you've lost me I thought we where talking about VBScript.

Comment: He is remembering older basics (including VBA) that accepted or corrected `EndIf` (but not `ElseIf`). It drove me crazy that VBS only accepted `End If` after decades of typing `EndIf`. VBS is the first basic that doesn't allow `EndIf`. We can also ask @EricLippert how he missed this from the VBA spec `LINE-START (("End" "If") / "EndIf")`.

Comment: @Noodles: First off, the initial implementation of VBScript was already done when I joined the team, so that wasn't my call. The design principle we decided on was that since there was no VBScript editor that autocorrected, we would *not* accept code that the VBA editor would autocorrect; we would accept only the correct code. If "EndIf" is legal and not autocorrected in VBA -- I do not recall -- then likely it was simply an oversight. The initial parser for VBScript was built very quickly and a lot of small details like that never got implemented.

Comment: The thing in VBA specs that I don't remember is `goto` and `go to` as well as `gosub` and `go sub`. I have never put a space after the Go

Comment: @Noodles: `EndIf` and `End If` have nothing to do with this question - I posted because I was getting my wires crossed (read my most recent comments prior to this). As for VBA, then this is actually down to the IDE, not the language.  I think that if you tried to force an `EndIf` through the compiler you'd have problems.

Comment: @EricLippert: Wow! Nice to have support from *the* Man! :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That example code doesn't compile and produces the compilation error

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected 'End'

as I'd expect *(as [@ekkehard-horner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603855/ekkehard-horner) [point's out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439170/vbscript-elseif-vs-else-if/38439841#comment64284688_38439170))*.

I've never known `ElseIf` to work any other way then [detailed in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The only thing I can think of is you are writing it as a nested `If` statement.

```vb
If a = b Then
    ...
Else If a = c Then
    ...
End If
End If
```

which looks really ugly but is the same as writing

```vb
If a = b Then
    ...
Else
    If a = c Then
        ...
    End If
End If
```

Problem with this approach is you end up with an un-handled condition on the nested `If` statement. What happens if `a = d` for example?

You would need to make sure your nested `If` caught the extra condition which isn't needed with an `ElseIf` statement.

```vb
If a = b Then
    ...
Else
    If a = c Then
        ...
    Else
        ...
    End If
End If
```

`ElseIf` approach would be;

```vb
If a = b Then
    ...
ElseIf a = c Then
    ...
Else
    ...
End If
```

---

[Interesting musing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439170/elseif-vs-else-if#comment64285575_38439170) by [@eric-lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) *(one of the programmers behind the VBScript compiler)* in the sea of comments...well worth a read. I certainly learned something.

Answer (score 3):

`Else If` puts a nested `If` inside the `Else` branch of the first `If` statement whereas `ElseIf` is part of the initial `If` statement.

Basically it's two 2-way conditionals (one nested in the other)

```
If condition Then
  ...
Else
  If condition Then
    ...
  Else
    ...
  End If
End If
```

vs one n-way conditional

```
If condition Then
  ...
ElseIf condition Then
  ...
Else
  ...
End If
```

And, as [@Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439170/vbscript-elseif-vs-else-if/38439829#comment64284688_38439170) pointed out, the former should raise an error without a closing nested `End If`.